# Selecting Elements with more than one Class in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some message elements like this...

```
<span class="error message">Whoops!  Don't forget your name.</span>
```

And...

```
<span class="success message">All done!  Thank you very much.</span>
```

You'll notice that two classes are being applied to a single `span` element.  This is valid markup.  How can I select elements with two classes like this?

Note:  I don't want all elements that have a class attribute containing "message".  I need the elements that have both "error" and "message" (and nothing else).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('.error.message')
```

should do it.

Comment: Note that this is also the correct syntax for a CSS definition for an element with multiple classes.

Comment: Take a look at all the possibilities in CSS 3 Selectors - they're awesome. When taking into account the fact that jQuery supports pretty much all of them, it means you have awesome power over your DOM.

Comment: As does Prototype in version 1.6.1 (due out any day), as both jQuery and Prototype use the same underlying **Sizzle** selection engine from John Resig.